# Alternative to the filter comment_reply_link

Tags: comments, filters, actions

I'm making a plugin and need to add a link to every comment on the front-end. I've used the filter `comment_reply_link` but that filter doesn't work when we're on the lowest level of threaded comments (since the reply link won't be shown).

Using the filter `comment_text` works somewhat, but places the link at an awkward place when the reply link is there. I could reposition it using javascript but for posts with many comments that could put too much strain on the visitors browser.

Is there a filter, action or another solution that works the same as `comment_reply_link` but will always show up?